# how to specify two filters in chrome extension mv3 declarativeNetRequest

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension using declarativeNetRequest to block request. I am able to apply following rule succssfully.

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "block"
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "www\\.(abc|def)\\.xyz\\.com/",
      "resourceTypes": [
        "main_frame"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Now I want to add another regexFilter condition to block request when both old and new regexFilters are matched. I know I can try to combine two regexFilter into a single regular expression. But is there anyway to specify two regular expressions in a rule?

Comment: The only way is to make a combined regex, but if your condition is simple you can use requestDomains instead of regexFilter. BTW current condition incorrectly matches also inside the path/query section of a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [woxxom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), I will combine the filters.